# Efficient way to implement 'events since x' in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization

I want to be-able to ask an object 'how many events have occurred in the last x seconds' where the x is an argument.

e.g. how many events have occurred in the last 120 seconds..

How I approached is linear based on the number of events occurring but was wanting to see what the most efficient way (space & time) to achieve this requirement?;

```
public class TimeSinceStat {
private List<DateTime> eventTimes = new ArrayList<>();

public void apply() {
            eventTimes.add(DateTime.now());
           }


public int eventsSince(int seconds) {
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.now().minus(Seconds.seconds(seconds));
    for (int i = 0; i < orderTimes.size(); i++) {
        DateTime dateTime = eventTimes.get(i);
        if (dateTime.compareTo(startTime) > 0)
            return eventTimes.subList(i, eventTimes.size()).size();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(PS - i'm using JodaTime for the date/time representation)

Edit:

The key of this algorithm to find all events that have happened in the last x seconds; the exact start time (e.g. now - 30 seconds) is may or maynot be in the collection

Comment: I think this kind of questions should be in Code Review rather than in SO

Comment: @Pablo fits in this site as well.

Comment: @Pablo no way. This is a great data structure/algorithm question.

Comment: What is "constant based on number events occurring" supposed to mean?  Because this seams to be linear in number of events occurring.  The more events, the longer it'll take.

Comment: @Ian, are you trying to optimize by reducing storage, or are you trying to retrieve/compute the results faster, or...?

Comment: Also, there's another potential trade off here.  If you are willing for *insertion* of the events to be very inefficient, you can get much more efficient querying.  So context is kind of important here.

Comment: @goat - both, something that would pass code review as well (i.e. easy to follow for a standard java developer)..

Comment: I can think of method which would provide constant space and time, but it quickly degrades towards O(n) time unless youre recording events very frequently. Eg, if you generally have at least one event per second, it would work very well in that type of workload. But, I wouldn't expect the code impl it to be overly easy to understand.

Comment: Iterating your current list in reverse, counting at each step, and stopping as soon as you go out of bounds of the time period would be more efficient than the suggested treeset solution. It's also very easy to understand, IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the `DateTime` in a `TreeSet` and then use `tailSet` to get the most recent events.  This saves you from having to find the starting point by iteration (which is `O(n)`) and instead by searching (which is `O (log n)`).

```
TreeSet<DateTime> eventTimes;

public int eventsSince(int seconds) {
    return eventTimes.tailSet(DateTime.now().minus(Seconds.seconds(seconds)), true).size();
}
```

Of course, you could also binary search on your sorted list, but this does the work for you.

### Edit

If it's a concern that multiple events could occur at the same `DateTime`, you can take the exact same approach with a [`SortedMultiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/SortedMultiset.html) from Guava:

```
TreeMultiset<DateTime> eventTimes;

public int eventsSince(int seconds) {
    return eventTimes.tailMultiset(
        DateTime.now().minus(Seconds.seconds(seconds)),
        BoundType.CLOSED
    ).size();
}
```

### Edit x2

Here's a much more efficient approach that leverages the fact that you only log events that happened after all other events.  With each event, store the number of events up to that date:

```
SortedMap<DateTime, Integer> eventCounts = initEventMap();

public SortedMap<DateTime, Integer> initEventMap() {
    TreeMap<DateTime, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
    //prime the map to make subsequent operations much cleaner
    map.put(DateTime.now().minus(Seconds.seconds(1)), 0);
    return map;
}

private long totalCount() {
    //you can handle the edge condition here
    return eventCounts.getLastEntry().getValue();
}

public void logEvent() {
    eventCounts.put(DateTime.now(), totalCount() + 1);
}
```

Then getting the count since a date is super efficient, just take the total and subtract the count of events that occurred *before* that date.

```
public int eventsSince(int seconds) {
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.now().minus(Seconds.seconds(seconds));
    return totalCount() - eventCounts.lowerEntry(startTime).getValue();
}
```

This eliminates the inefficient iteration.  It's a constant time lookup and an `O(log n)` lookup.

Comment: @goat: sure It's sorted, but he's not taking advantage of that.

Comment: @MarkPeters - Correct me if i'm wrong but this expects for a exact match to be in the set but in the real world this may not be case (we look for the element count after a specific time)

Comment: @Ian: Nope, tailSet works how you would hope.  If the startTime is not in the set, it takes everything after it.  That works because elements are comparable, including the value you're searching for.  I accidentally omitted a relevant detail: a second parameter to `tailSet` and `tailMultiset` determines if it should be inclusive or exclusive (i.e. `>=` or `>` the passed element)

Answer (score 3):

If you were implementing a data structure from scratch, and the data are not in sorted order, you'd want to construct a balanced [order statistic tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree) (also see [code here](http://pine.cs.yale.edu/pinewiki/OrderStatisticsTree)). This is just a regular balanced tree with the size of the tree rooted at each node maintained in the node itself.

The size fields enable efficient calcualtion of the "rank" of any key in the tree.  You can do the desired range query by making two O(log n) probes into the tree for the rank of the min and max range value, finally taking their difference.

The proposed tree and set tail operations are great except the tail views will need time to construct, even though all you need is their size. The asymptotic complexity is the same as the OST, but the OST avoids this overhead completely.  The difference could be meaningful if performance is very criticial.

Of course I'd definitely use the standard library solution first and consider the OST only if the speed turned out to be inadequate.

Comment: +1, this seems like a great approach if you're willing to use a non-standard lib.  On the point of "the tail views will need time to construct", as these are live views, I don't know that this is actually expensive.  I think it's constant time.  However, from what I saw of the code, getting the resulting `size()` *would* require iteration over the tail set in the implementations I saw.

Comment: @MarkPeters  Absolutely right.  I meant only a constant factor of overhead. The iteration to get `size()` would be amortized.  That's why I said asytmptotic performance remains the same.  There would also be a difference in young generation GC load. The OST would be garbage free.

Answer (score 0):

Since `DateTime` already implements `Comparable` interface, I would recommend storing the data in a `TreeMap` instead, and you could use [`TreeMap#tailMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#tailMap-K-boolean-) to get a subtree of the `DateTime`'s that occurs in the desired time.

Based on your code:

```
public class TimeSinceStat {
    //just in case two or more events start at the "same time"
    private NavigableMap<DateTime, Integer> eventTimes = new TreeMap<>();
    //if this class needs to be used in multiple threads, use ConcurrentSkipListMap instead of TreeMap

    public void apply() {
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
        Integer times = eventTimes.contains(dateTime) != null ? 0 : (eventTimes.get(dateTime) + 1);
        eventTimes.put(dateTime, times);
    }

    public int eventsSince(int seconds) {
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.now().minus(Seconds.seconds(seconds));
        NavigableMap<DateTime, Integer> eventsInRange = eventTimes.tailMap(startTime, true);
        int counter = 0;
        for (Integer time : eventsInRange.values()) {
            counter += time;
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Comment: @goat so? `TreeMap` also has the data sorted and handles the algorithm in O(log n), while using the `List` approach takes `O(n)`, and its usage would be of 1 line.

Comment: @goat but it's not sorted by event time - OP is recommended to store it in a structure sorted by event time

Comment: OP it's storing only the time, not the event, so I think a Set suits better than a Map

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the list is sorted, you could do a binary search. Java Collections already provides `Collections.binarySearch`, and `DateTime` implements `Comparable` (according to the JodaTime JavaDoc). `binarySearch` will return the index of the value you want, if it exists in the list, otherwise it returns the index of the greatest value less than the one you want (with the sign flipped). So, all you need to do is (in your `eventsSince` method):

```
// find the time you want.
int index=Collections.binarySearch(eventTimes, startTime);
if(index < 0) index = -(index+1)-1; // make sure we get the right index if startTime isn't found
// check for dupes
while(index != eventTimes.size() - 1 && eventTimes.get(index).equals(eventTimes.get(index+1))){
    index++;
}
// return the number of events after the index
return eventTimes.size() - index; // this works because indices start at 0
```

This should be a faster way to do what you want.

Comment: Of course, there are a lot of caveats to this approach as well.  a) what if startTime isn't in the list?  b) What if there are multiple events at startTime in the list?

Comment: @MarkPeters I already explained (please read my answer fully) that if startTime isn't in the list, binarySearch returns the index of the greatest value less than the one you want. However, I'm not sure about multiple events at startTime, I'll do some tests later.

Comment: Oh no. The javadoc for `Collections.binarySearch` says `If the list contains multiple elements equal to the specified object, there is no guarantee which one will be found.` That's a problem.

Comment: No, it doesn't return the index of the greatest value less than the one you want.  It returns `-(insertionPoint - 1)`.  You need to do some arithmetic to turn that into a useful number.

Comment: Whoops misread the javadoc... And I fixed it as well. My code turned out to be really buggy didn't it... (joys of being a developer I guess)